# push to vc from UIView class under a view controller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, navigation, scrollview

created a class,
GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView : UIView,
to add multiple view into a scroll view,
the view comes up with buttons which are linked to a selector that is supposed to push to another view controller, It sends the placeID back up but from some reason doesn't push to the next view controller

GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView.h

```
#import "featureScreenViewController.h"

@interface GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView : UIView
{
    UIImageView* imageView;
    UILabel* titleLabel;
    UILabel* distanceLabel;
    UILabel* descriptionLabel;
    UIButton* pushButton;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSString* placeID;

-(void)setLocationInfo:(NSString*)ID title:(NSString*)title distance:(double)distance description:(NSString*)description imageURL:(NSString*)imageURL;

@end
```

GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView.m

```
#import "GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView.h"
#import "GSSLocationDetailViewController.h"


@implementation GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView
@synthesize placeID = _placeID;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 144, 140)];
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 148, 107, 21)];
        distanceLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 177, 107, 21)];
        descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 206, 107, 91)];
        pushButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 144, 317)];

        [titleLabel setText:@""];
        [distanceLabel setText:@""];
        [descriptionLabel setText:@""];
        [descriptionLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        [pushButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [pushButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushToLocation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [self addSubview:titleLabel];
        [self addSubview:distanceLabel];
        [self addSubview:descriptionLabel];
        [self addSubview:pushButton];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setLocationInfo:(NSString *)ID title:(NSString *)title distance:(double)distance description:(NSString *)description imageURL:(NSString *)imageURL
{
    _placeID = ID;
    [titleLabel setText:title];
    [distanceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", distance]];
    [descriptionLabel setText:description];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageURL];
    [imageView setImage:image];

}



-(void) pushToLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    featureScreenViewController* fsvc = [[featureScreenViewController alloc]init];
    [fsvc pushToLocationWithID:_placeID]; 
}

@end
```

in featureScreenViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE
    if (isiPhone5)
    {
        // this is iphone 4 inch
        [scroller setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 251, 320, 317)];
    }
    else
    {
        [scroller setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 251, 320, 229)];
    }
    [self addLocationViews];
}

-(void)addLocationViews
{
    int count = (int)[_placeArray count];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(152*count, 317)];
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        _placeObject = [_placeArray objectAtIndex:i];

        GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView * view = [[GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((152*i), 0, 144, 317)];
        [view setLocationInfo:[_placeObject placeID] title:[_placeObject placeName] distance:[_placeObject distacne] description:@"description" imageURL:@"noImage.png"];

        [scroller addSubview:view];
    }

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

}

-(void) pushToLocationWithID:(NSString*)placeID
{
    NSLog(@"\n%s \nplaceID:%@\n\n", __FUNCTION__, placeID);
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    GSSLocationDetailViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GSSLocationDetailViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

the function -(void) pushToLocationWithID:(NSString*)placeID is called and the log shows the function and placeID, However it doesn't push to the location view controller.
tried creating a button just to link a segue to it and called the performSegue with identifier, doesn't reach prepare for segue and still doesn't push.

However using the same code from another page in an IBAction and it works. Is there someway to call super or something so it goes into the navController and pushes it  ?

If i do presentViewController just to test modal like shown above it shows

```
Warning: Attempt to present <GSSLocationDetailViewController: 0xab85110> on <featureScreenViewController: 0xab9c230> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

but if i do

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

it doesn't show anything in the log and doesn't push.

made a new project with same concept at http://www.narula-tech.com/testScrollPush.zip

Comment: If you want to present from a view controller, that ViewController's view should be in window.

Comment: i want to push it, tried present just to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a `UIView` (`GSSFeatureScreenLocationTabView`) and you are allocating a new `viewController` (**VC2**: `featureScreenViewController`) from there and you are pushing another `viewController` (**VC3**: `GSSLocationDetailViewController`) from there.

But actually your view is in another viewController **VC1** and you need to push **VC3** from there and not from **VC2** which you are allocating but is not "in the scene" or better, in the window hierarchy.

So you should control touches from the viewController and not from the UIView..for this reason the name: view**CONTROLLER**.

Another thing but not related:
name of class should began with the **first letter capitol**:

So not:

```
featureScreenViewController* fsvc;
```

but:

```
FeatureScreenViewController* fsvc;
```

Comment: i declared that class with a small letter so its featureScreenViewController (the rest start with a capital, forgot to press shift for this one o.O)... and I'm at VC1 which has multiple views in a scrollview, trying to get to VC2 from there.

Comment: so do i do [super pushToViewController:vc]; ? in the uiview file ?

Comment: No, you should control touches from the viewController and not from the UIView..for this reason the name: viewCONTROLLER

Comment: So, I generate the views in the controller itself ?, thnx for being patient.. I'm noobish at this

Comment: Your viewContoller has a view where you are adding more view. There many ways to control this aspect, but for sure, you can't push a view controller from a view, but only from another viewController. For this reason you should control the view from your viewController. I don't know where you generate the view, it is a your choice. Probably being a newbie you couldn't use the best architecture, but you will improve. The problem in your code is big because you are allocating a viewController, but that viewController is not presented.

Comment: Created a view in featureScreen itself and added tag to buttons to save the info, to push to next page.